# Calling services from Remote server in Azure

Tags: web-services, azure, remote-server

I'm developing a LMS application in VS-2012 with SQL server 2008 R2.I have a web service hosted in my local server.I don't want this to be published or moved to Azure
rather I would like to make a call of this service (remote server) from Azure.
How do I achieve them?
I'm very new to the Azure technology.Kindly explain in brief.

Answer (score 0):

If the local server is public so it can be reach from internet you can just call it. However if its on your local network and you don't want to expose it you will have to connect it to an Azure Virtual network using VPN, [read more here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690124.aspx)